# What is causing a black screen while switching spaces on Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac, macos, spaces, mission-control

On Lion I used to see the next space wallpaper while pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to switch desktops. But on Mountain Lion I see a Black Screen until the transition is complete. Is it just me who is facing this issue or is this the new behaviour in Mountain Lion?

Comment: That's not the intended behavior. Does it happen on other accounts or a guest account?

Comment: This is currently happening on my main admin account. I will try creating other account and report back in a minute :)

Comment: Happened to me in OSX El Capitan. The cause was 'Console'. Closed it and the black screen vanished.

Answer (score 3):

Its now resolved. It was not an issue with OSX. I was using a software called ScreenShade which was causing this issue. Disabling ScreenShade resolved the issue.

Comment: same thing happens with Isolator (http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/)